# JSON Behavior with .put() and .accumulate() retroactively changing values

Tags: java, json, put, accumulate

I am having a rather odd interaction when attempting to accumulate multiple objects into a JSONObject.

I am using json-20180813.jar imported library

See code below

```
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    JSONObject masterobject = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject testobject = new JSONObject();

    testobject.put("Key1","Value1");
    testobject.put("Key2","Value2");
    masterobject.accumulate("masterkey1",testobject);
    System.out.println(masterobject.toString(1));
    System.out.println("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");

    testobject.put("Key1","Value3");
    System.out.println(masterobject.toString(1));
```

The expected output would be something like:

masterkey {value2 value1}

not masterkey {value2 value3}

Instead I end up with this

```
{"masterkey1": {
 "Key2": "Value2",
 "Key1": "Value1"
}}
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
{"masterkey1": {
 "Key2": "Value2",
 "Key1": "Value3"
}}
```

my question is, why does .put() have an effect on masterkey?

NOTE: This issue is solved if I were to use a second new JSONObject() and accumulate that object instead, however I want to understand why .put() edits another object.

Answer (score 0):

The problems is that `.put()` is modifying the object that is stored under the `masterkey1` key.

Since in Java everything is represented using pointers and not value, when you modify **testobject** you also see the change in **masterobject**

Comment: Would this also be the same for a hashmap using .put()?



So masterobject despite having called accumulate, (in some cases ends up being put) is not functioning as append but instead 'puts' of pointers in a immutable object?



JSONObjects are immutable by the documentation, Am I misunderstanding how pointers work inside a immutable object?